# What is the difference between a potential divider and a potentiometer?

Tags: voltage-divider, potentiometer

It would be nice if I could get an elaborate answer which highlights the difference between their functional aspects.

Comment: You want a treatise on the topic?

Comment: A potentiometer is a device. A potential divider is a class of devices and circuits.

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: @jsotola No it isn't.

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBXkXT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) A potential divider. (b) A potentiometer.*

- A potential divider is made of two resistances, usually fixed.
- A potentiometer is a resistor with an adjustable tap-off point. It performs the same function as the potential divider but can be varied without replacing components.

The output voltage is a function of the resistance values each side of the tap-off and the voltages at each end. The load being driven by the divider will also affect the divider voltage.

Answer (score 3):

A potential divider is a sub-circuit, a potentiometer is a device.

A potential divider may be constructed with from fixed resistors, or from resistive sensors, or some combination, or you could use a potentiometer. A potentiometer is always a fixed resistor with a movable tap. (and usuaally a knob or handle, or a place to mount such)

While it's often used as a potential divider a potentiometer can also be used in ways that cause it not to divide potential (eg with the wiper grounded, or shorted to one end)